# Update all local docker images through console command

Tags: docker

I need to update all docker images through console command. Full list:

```
andrey@BushM1 ~ % docker images --format "{{.Repository}}" | sort --unique               
bitnami/kafka
bitnami/zookeeper
confluentinc/cp-kafka
confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect
confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
denoland/deno
mariadb
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk
mongo
mongo-express
mysql
node
portainer/portainer-ce
postgres
provectuslabs/kafka-ui
python
rabbitmq
redis
traefik
vault
wordpress
andrey@BushM1 ~ %
```

I need something like this:

```
andrey@BushM1 ~ % docker pull $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}" | sort --unique)
"docker pull" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker pull --help'.

Usage:  docker pull [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG|@DIGEST]

Pull an image or a repository from a registry
andrey@BushM1 ~ %
```

How to write right iteration?

Comment: `docker pull` only takes one argument, so write a loop

Comment: @Paolo how to do it in a single command (I expected through pipes) without creating bash script?

Comment: Why does it have to be a single command?

Comment: @Paolo I learn linux and it is interesting for me.

Comment: use `xargs`, it does the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a typical job for xargs:

```
docker images --format "{{.Repository}}" | sort -u | xargs -n1 docker pull
```

See `man xargs` for more options. You can also just do a loop:

```
.... | while IFS= read -r line; do docker pull "$line"; done
```